# Javascript callback functions for composite controls

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have defined an object in javascript which represents an asp.net server control.

The server control defines a client callback method that basically retrieves the data that needs to be displayed in the control.

The controls life cycle is as follows:
The control is created on the server for the aspx page
The Pre-Render function attaches a client script to create the javascript control on window.load
The client script initializes the object and attempts to retrieve the data
once the data is received, the object displays its data

The problem I am facing is that when I add more then one of these custom controls, the callback for the data is only ever being executed for the last control added.

Example:
Control1 is created on the aspx page;
Control1 initializes, calls the function to get data
Control2 is created;
Control2 initializes, calls the function to get data
Control2 receives its data

Uniquely specific callback function names and settings timeouts dont work

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this suggests that for each control you drop into the page, then each control will need it VERY own on. load() function. And it is legal to have multiple controls.

So, for example, I made a user control out of Gauge.js. The issue was for each control I drop into the form, I need:

a div for the control - but without conflicting id.

I need a JavaScript var to hold some settings for the gauge and that div.

And I needed a on.load() event for each control.

Obviously then, if I drop in the control 3 times into the page, then I'll need 3 on.load() events. And each will have to refer to a different instance of the control, and div and JavaScript var then, right?

So, that means your script for each user control (or server control) will have to "change" or use server-side expressions for each instance of the control.

So, I have code like this in the user control. (server controls will work the same).

So then this:

```
<div id="<%= Me.ID %>" 
       style="float:left;width:<%=Me.Width%>;height:<%=Me.Height%>">
</div>

    <script>

        var <%= Me.ID %>

            $(window).on('load', function () {

                <%= Me.ID %> = new JustGage({
                    id: "<%= Me.ID %>",
                    value: <%= Me.Value %>,
                    min: <%= Me.Min %>,
                    max: <%= Me.Max %>,
                    label: "<%= Me.Label%>",
                    showInnerShadow: true,
                    shadowOpacity: 2,
                    shadowSize: 5,
                    startAnimationTime: 2000,
                    startAnimationType: ">",
                    refreshAnimationTime: 7000,
                    refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
                    donut: <%= Me.Donut %>,
                    counter: true,
                    relativeGaugeSize: true,
                    valueFontColor: "<%= Me.FontColor %>",
                    labelFontColor: "<%= Me.FontColor %>",
                    guageColor: "<%= Me.GaugeColor %>",
                    levelColors: [
                        "#00fff6",
                        "#ff00fc",
                        "#1200ff"
                    ]
                });

            });

    </script>
```

So, note how we have a $(window).on('load') function. And obvious that the JavaScript thus injected into the page will be for the SPECIFIC control.

If I drop the control in 3 times, then the control will have 3 different id's, and that jQuery on-load code will in fact have 3 copies of the code, each being different. So, I'll wind up with 3 on.load() events and copy of that code in the one page.

So, you are allowed multiple on.load() JavaScript stubs, and no need to have just one on.load() JavaScript code stub (I used jQuery in above, but it don't really matter).

Now, above was a user control, and not a server control, but they are rather similar in how both such controls are created.

So, it not clear if your on.load code is hard coded to the ONE instance of the control, but, you if need the on.load JavaScript code to work correctly for EACH instance of the control you drop on the page, and thus the variables etc. will have to reflect that. Hence, the variable names in the code are defined with server-side expressions (reflecting the one instance).

And in some cases, I'll EVEN have the name of the function based on the id, and hence then this:

```
    var ucMyPopDialogOK = false
    function <%= Me.ID %>ucPOP(btn) {

        var ucCtrlID = '<%= Me.ID  %>'
        var ucTitle = "<%= Me.Title  %>"
        var ucBody = '<%= Me.Body %>'
        var ucPos = <%= Me.Position %>
        var ucPopDiv = '<%= Me.PopDiv %>' 
        var ucWidth = '<%= Me.Width %>' 
        var ucBokText = '<%= Me.BOkText %>'
        var ucOkIcon = '<%= Me.IconOkS %>'
        var ucCancelText = "<%= Me.BCancelText %>"
        var ucCancelIcon = '<%= Me.IconCancelS %>'
        var ucDismissable = <%= Me.Dissmissable %>
        var ucDefaultButton = <%= me.DefaultButton %>
```

So, in above, the JavaScript function injected to the page is based on "id" of the user control, and then appended with ucPOP. That way, I have a 100% separate copy of the JavaScript routines for that one instance of that user control.

(this is a user jQuery dialog control to pop any div on a page with great ease).

So, once again, if each instance of the control needs a specific JavaScript function to run, and be based on the ONE instance of the control? Then as above shows, the JavaScript function name is based on the control id + ucPOP. And thus, yes, if the control is dropped 3 times on the page, then I have 3 copies of that JavaScript routine. However, with a function name being separate, then the vars used inside of that function don't have to be server side, since they are local to the one instance of the JavaScript function.

I suppose with "more" efforts on my part, the above 2nd JavaScript example should be placed on the page ONE time, and then each control could call that one shared JavaScript routine (passing values). However, I did not think that's worth the extra efforts, and thus I live with multiple copies of the JavaScript code required to run that dialog example. No doubt, for a much larger JavaScript routine, then I would want only one copy of the routine to exist in a given web page.

So, I don't see why multiple instances can't call a web method if they each have their own on.load() code stub, or even just code to call some web method.

However, I don't think having each control call the ONE code stub routine that already waiting for a web method response will work.